# VBA code to add row to bottom of table in excel not just specified row on sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have an existing spreadsheet in Excel 2010 linked via power query to other worksheets to reference data.  On the sheet named "Shop Dwg" the macro to `AddRow` currently adds the first row to the table by referencing "B10" which is the first blank row beneath a header of a table named "ShpDwg".

The `AddRow` feature also populates the "B" and "C" cell of the row with information gleaned from other sheets in the workbook.

The macro works very well but since the rows are added consistently at "B10", it pushes the other rows down and thus the sequential numbering in column "B" ends up being in descending order.  I would rather have the new rows added to the bottom of the table so that the data in column "B" is in ascending order. How can I achieve that ?

Here is the current code:

```
Sub AddRow()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect

    If Sheets("Shop Dwg").Rows(10).Hidden = True Then
        If Sheets("Info").Range("D4").Value = "" Or Sheets("Info").Range("D5") = "" Then
            MsgBox "Please enter the Job and Drawing details on the Info tab First"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Sheets("Shop Dwg").Shapes.Range(Array("DELETEARROW")).Delete
        Sheets("Shop Dwg").Rows(10).Hidden = False
        Sheets("Shop Dwg").Range("B10").Value = Sheets("Info").Range("D4").Value & "/" & Sheets("Info").Range("D5").Value & "-1"
        Sheets("Shop Dwg").Range("C10").Value = Sheets("Info").Range("D3").Value & "-" & Sheets("Jobs").Range("S2").Value

    Else
        Range("ShpDwg[Mtl ID]").ListObject.ListRows.Add (1)
        Sheets("Shop Dwg").Range("B10").Value = 0
        Sheets("Shop Dwg").Range("B10" & LastRow).Value = Sheets("Info").Range("D4").Value & "/" & Sheets("Info").Range("D5").Value & "-" & Sheets("Jobs").Range("U2").Value
        Sheets("Shop Dwg").Range("C10" & LastRow).Value = Sheets("Info").Range("D3").Value & "-" & Sheets("Jobs").Range("S2").Value

    End If

    Range("d10").Select

    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=True, AllowDeletingRows _
        :=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables _
        :=True, UserInterfaceOnly:=True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

If anyone can help me with this it would be appreciated.

Here is the code that I updated the above with to stop it from referencing a position to referencing the last row of the table.

```
Else
    Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
        Dim tbl As ListObject
        Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("ShpDwg")
        Dim newrow As ListRow
        Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add
        With newrow
        .Range(1) = 0
        .Range(1) = Sheets("Info").Range("D4").Value & "/" & Sheets("Info").Range("D5").Value & "-" & Sheets("Jobs").Range("U2").Value
        .Range(2) = Sheets("Info").Range("D3").Value & "-" & Sheets("Jobs").Range("S2").Value
    End With

    End If
    Range("d10").Select
```

Comment: Just don't specify a position `Range("ShpDwg[Mtl ID]").ListObject.ListRows.Add`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Forgive me for my ignorance as I am modifying this table that someone else created for me.  How do I change it from a position to the table?

Comment: I believed I have solved it by changing the code as follows:

Comment: Else
    Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
        Dim tbl As ListObject
        Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("ShpDwg")
        Dim newrow As ListRow
        Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add
        With newrow
        .Range(1) = 0
        .Range(1) = Sheets("Info").Range("D4").Value & "/" & Sheets("Info").Range("D5").Value & "-" & Sheets("Jobs").Range("U2").Value
        .Range(2) = Sheets("Info").Range("D3").Value & "-" & Sheets("Jobs").Range("S2").Value
    End With
    
    End If
    Range("d10").Select

Comment: Can you add code to your question please - as you can see it doesn't format properly in comments. What I meant was that if you don't specify a position as in the line I quoted it adds the row to the bottom of the table.

Comment: Your comment of not specifying a position helped me.  In my original question I posted the code that I was able to use to solve my problem.